# Number of elements of the set

Tags: combinatorics

Let $m$ and $M$ be positive integer numbers, $m<M$, and let
$$
A=\{(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_k) \mid m \leq \alpha_1 < \alpha_2 < \cdots < \alpha_k \leq M\}.
$$
Find the number of elements of the set $A$.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I think you want to say that the $\alpha_i$ are integers.

Answer (score 3):

There are $M-m+1$ numbers between $m$ and $M$ inclusive. You can choose any subset of them (ignoring order) and then force an ascending order on them without overcounting. So the answer is $\binom{M-m+1}{k}$.